# Printing text between org tags

Tags: bash

I would like to write a bash function that prints sections of text enclosed between lines matching `## mode: org` and `## # End of org` in a file, with an empty line between sections.  Before the `##`, there can be any number of spaces though.

Here is an example of a file to extract information from.

```
file: test.sh

## mode: org
## * Using case statement
## # End of org
case $arg in
 ("V")
   echo "Author"
   ;;
 (*)
   ## mode: org
   ## ** Silent Error Reporting Mode (SERM) in getopts
   ## *** Detects warnings without printing built-in messages.
   ## *** Enabled by colon {:} as first character in shortopts.
   ## # End of org
   break
   ;;
esac
```

The desired output would be

```
* Using case statement

** Silent Error Reporting Mode (SERM) in getopts
*** Detects warnings without printing built-in messages.
*** Enabled by colon {:} as first character in shortopts.
```

I have done it with

```
capture-org ()
{
  sed -n '/^ *## mode: org$/,/^ *## # End of org$/s/ *//p' "$1" |
   sed 's/^## mode: org$/\n## mode: org/' |
   sed '/^## mode: org$/d' | sed '/^## # End of org$/d' | cut -c 3-
}
```

Can it be done in a neater fashion?

Comment: 1. What have you tried? What happened when you tried it?  2. This is a job for a text processing tool like sed or awk or perl, not for bash itself (although you can use these tools in a shell script or function - that's what shell is for).

Comment: possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or

Comment: If the above comment doesn't cover your use-case.. you can try: `awk '/mode: org/{f=1; print ""; next} /End of org/{f=0} { gsub(/\s*#/,"") } f'`  or change `\s*` to `[[:blank:]]`

Comment: And maybe a simpler one is: `awk '/mode: org/{f=1; print ""; next} /End of org/{f=0} { gsub(/#/,""); $1=$1 } f' testthis`

Comment: @Fatipati I updated my answer, (assuming a couple of things).

Comment: @Fatipati does the file contain other comment blocks similar to the ones you show but enclosed in different strings than `## mode: org` , etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*## mode: org$/,/^[[:space:]]*## # End of org$/!d; /^[[:space:]]*## mode: org$/d; s/^[[:space:]]*## # End of org$//g; s/^[[:space:]]*## //'
```

This will delete everything that is not within the start and end patterns. Then it will remove the start pattern and replace the end pattern with an empty line (which becomes the block separator).

Comment: I can look into using it.

Comment: In your last replacement pattern, the hashes and following single spaces should also be matched and removed according to OP's desired output: `s/^[[:space:]]*## //`

Comment: You're right, I missed that part, thanks!